# How UTF-8 support can be achieved through rest api

Tags: rest, jaxb

How to provide only UTF-8 data through rest api? how to escape from special characters lilke  (Ã¯Â¿Â?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default JAXB will convert Java objects to XML that is UTF-8 encoded.  If you are using JAXB directly or indirectly through JAX-RS you will get the necessary escaping automatically.

Comment: Inside CDATA it is breaking.

Comment: @rose - Using just the standard APIs JAXB can't produce CData.  Are you using an extension?